# PowerBi -All visualizations change when I apply a filter

Tags: powerbi

I'm working on a dashboard in Powerbi, but when I change a filter or a variable, instead of applying the changes to the selected view, they apply to all views on the page. What would be the setting to adjust this?

Tentei aopção de aplicar filtros de busca detalhadas, mas não funcionou

Comment: See [Change how visuals interact in a Power BI report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-reports-visual-interactions?tabs=powerbi-desktop)